# Add a counter beside menu item label

Tags: menus, filters, hooks, navigation

I'm using the following code to add a panel to the admin menu screen, so the users are able to add a Cart link to their menus:

```
function my_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 'custom-meta-box', __( 'Cart' ), 'my_nav_menu_item_link_meta_box', 'nav-menus', 'side', 'default' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_add_meta_box' );

function my_nav_menu_item_link_meta_box() {
    global $_nav_menu_placeholder, $nav_menu_selected_id;
    $_nav_menu_placeholder = 0 > $_nav_menu_placeholder ? $_nav_menu_placeholder - 1 : -1;
    ?>
    <div id="posttype-cart" class="posttypediv">
        <div id="tabs-panel-cart" class="tabs-panel tabs-panel-active">
            <ul id="cart-checklist" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">
                <li>
                    <label class="menu-item-title">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="menu-item-checkbox" name="menu-item[<?php echo (int) $_nav_menu_placeholder; ?>][menu-item-object-id]" value="-1"> <?php esc_html_e( 'Cart' ); ?>
                    </label>
                    <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-type" name="menu-item[<?php echo (int) $_nav_menu_placeholder; ?>][menu-item-type]" value="post_type">
                    <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-object" name="menu-item[<?php echo (int) $_nav_menu_placeholder; ?>][menu-item-object]" value="page">
                    <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-object-id" name="menu-item[<?php echo (int) $_nav_menu_placeholder; ?>][menu-item-object-id]" value="<?php echo get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_page_id' ); ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-title" name="menu-item[<?php echo (int) $_nav_menu_placeholder; ?>][menu-item-title]" value="<?php esc_html_e( 'Cart' ); ?>">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <p class="button-controls">
            <span class="add-to-menu">
                <input type="submit" <?php disabled( $nav_menu_selected_id, 0 ); ?> class="button-secondary submit-add-to-menu right" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Add to Menu' ); ?>" name="add-post-type-menu-item" id="submit-posttype-cart">
                <span class="spinner"></span>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

My question is, is it possible to dynamically add a counter that shows the number of items in cart beside the Cart menu item label in the frontend? If so, how? I think that the `wp_get_nav_menu_items` filter might be useful for this, but how can I identify the Cart menu item in there to be able to modify its label in the frontend on the fly?

```
function my_get_nav_menu_items( $items ) {
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( is_cart_menu_item( $item ) ) {
            // add a counter beside the Cart menu item label    
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'my_get_nav_menu_items', 20 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Bhautik answer, I've found a solution to identify the cart menu link using the `woocommerce_cart_page_id` option:

```
function modify_cart_label_in_nav_menu_objects( $items, $args ) {
    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        if ( $item->object_id == (int) get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_page_id' ) ) {
            if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() > 0 ) {
                $item->title .= ' ('. WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . ')';
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'modify_cart_label_in_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [wp_nav_menu_objects](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_objects/) filter hook and you can compare your menu label with the condition and append your cart count. check below code. code will go active theme functions.php file. tested and works.

```
function modify_cart_label_in_nav_menu_objects( $items, $args ) {
    if($args->theme_location == 'primary'){ 
        foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
            if ( $item->title == 'test'  ) {
                $item->title .= '('.WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count().')';
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'modify_cart_label_in_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: But, what if the user changes the menu item label?

Comment: If you print `$item` you can see there is an id of the menu you can set conditions based on that.